# Include class library to controller in Laravel but doesn't found class

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to include class library to controller but when I run the page I've got

```
production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'MyClass' not found'...
```

I have added this class to app/libraries and in `composer.json` added this

```
"app/libraries",
```

Also I have tried to add it in `global.php`

```
app_path().'/libraries',
```

and still got this message. Any ideas and solutions on this?

Comment: Where inside composer.json have you added **app/libraries** and have you ran **composer dumpautoload** after that?

Comment: Thank's after dumpauload it's working

Comment: Great, I'll add this as an answer so question could be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `composer dumpautoload` to rebuild the autoloading files for your new class.